# gunicorn and python doesn't work when i close the bash terminal

Tags: python-2.7, centos, virtualenv, gunicorn

I have a python program running on a centos machine. I used virtualenv (source activate) to activate a specific python  and then I use the following command:

```
gunicorn -t 10000 -b 0.0.0.0:1234 start:app &
```

It works fine. But when i close the bash, my program doens't work anymore. when i open a new bash (through PUTTY),  and type

```
 ps -C gunicorn
```

i see the gunicorn process running.
If i put all this on local.rc (to initialize together with the server) everything works fine always.

I have two questions. First one is:

Can i put a "forever" on gunicorn (like we put on node.js), or dettach gunicorn and virtualenv from the bash, in order to always run independent of closing 
the bash?

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer. I tried to use nohup, with no success. Now i am using

```
gunicorn -t 10000 -b 0.0.0.0:1234 start:app  --daemon &
```

The --daemon option worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Probably nohup will help

```
nohup your command
```

[What's the difference between nohup and ampersand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595374/whats-the-difference-between-nohup-and-ampersand)

Also check the --daemon option, it could be similiar to forewer, for details and other suggestions see

[What is the correct way to leave gunicorn running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654688/what-is-the-correct-way-to-leave-gunicorn-running)